# How do you use the smoke bomb?

Tags: die2nite

We have a smoke bomb in our bank. It smells really nice, some kind of... pine scent. But, it is also reported to conceal your actions over the last 3 minutes and the next 1 minute.

However, I don't get to use it in my house. How does it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The description is misleading. **This item only works outside of town.** You can't use it to hide actions you take in town like raiding the bank or upgrading your hovel to a castle.

When you use it, it will conceal anything you do *in the zone you are standing in*.

Comment: That seems borderline useless to me.

Comment: Fun fact: I discovered this *after* I raided the bank and upgraded my hovel.